# Authorize Filter in Web Api 2.0 With OauthBearerTokens Not Working

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, asp.net-identity-2

I have a Single Page Application (Angular Js + AspNet Web API) using OAuthBearerToken style authentication

My Code Is as follows

```
[assembly: OwinStartupAttribute(typeof(App.Web.Startup))]
namespace App.Web
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
     public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
      {
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();
        config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();


        config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
        var jsonFormatter = config.Formatters.OfType<JsonMediaTypeFormatter>().First();
        jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();


        config.Filters.Add(new ValidateModelStateAttribute());
        config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        //register autofac
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.RegisterModelBinders(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        builder.RegisterFilterProvider();
        builder.RegisterModelBinderProvider();

        builder.RegisterWebApiFilterProvider(config);
        builder.RegisterWebApiModelBinders(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());


        var container = builder.Build();
        var resolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
        config.DependencyResolver = resolver;
        app.UseAutofacMiddleware(container);
        app.UseAutofacWebApi(config);
        app.UseWebApi(config);
        ConfigureOAuth(app, container);
    }

     public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app, IContainer container)
      {
        var oAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
        {
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),

            Provider = container.Resolve(typeof(SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider)) as IOAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
        };
        app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(oAuthServerOptions);
        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(oAuthServerOptions);
        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());

    }
}
```

}

My SimpleAuthorizationProvider Implementation is as listed below

```
 public class SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
  {

    public override async Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)

    {
        context.Validated();

    }
    public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {

        context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] {"*"});

        var userManager = context.OwinContext.GetAutofacLifetimeScope().Resolve<IUserStore<User>>() as UserStore;
        if (userManager != null)
        {
            var user = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(context.UserName);

            if (user == null)
            {
                context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
                return;
            }
            var phash = await userManager.GetPasswordHashAsync(user);
            //the hash of the incoming password
            var passwordHasher = new PasswordHasher();
            var result = passwordHasher.VerifyHashedPassword(phash, context.Password);

            if (result == PasswordVerificationResult.Success)
            {
                var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
                identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Sid, user.Id.ToString()));
                identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, user.UserName));
                context.Validated(identity);
                               }
            else
            {
                context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");

            }

        }
    }


}
```

Now here goes the problem
When I Issue a post request to the /token endpoint. Everything works well and I get a bearer token returned

Whenever i try to access an action method annotated with the authorize attribute with HTTP Authorization Header set to Bearer {access_token} I get the message

"Authorization has been denied for this request".

Please Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You should sent the token in the Authorization header using Bearer scheme.

I guess you are sending it as part of the query string, that is why your API protected endpoints are not understanding it. Please check my detailed post about [AngularJS authentication with Web API](http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/09/angularjs-token-authentication-using-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/) which covers your exact scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a `WebApiConfig.cs` file in your project, with  `Register(HttpConfiguration config)` method in it ?

If you do, then it should contain the following :

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{      
  // Move config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication() from Startup::Register method to this method
  config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();

  // Add a filter handling "Bearer" authentication to the known filters
  config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter("Bearer"));
}
```

I was having the same problem as you, and fixed it with this.
The solution was brought by https://stackoverflow.com/a/34166821/867600.

Answer (score -2):

how do you pass the header in your request ? it should be

Authorization: Bearer imSXTs2OqSrGWzsFQhIXziFCO3rF...

```
// If we already have a bearer token, set the Authorization header.
var token = sessionStorage.getItem(tokenKey);
var headers = {};
if (token) {
    headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + token;
}

$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
url: 'api/values/1',
headers: headers
}).done(function (data) {
self.result(data);
}).fail(showError);
```

see this [link](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api), it has a very good details.

Hope that helps.